# switch error in iOS

Tags: ios, switch-statement, uialertview

I try to do different function by using switch

```
   switch (self.requestID) {
            case 0:
                [self setTableData:[jsonDic objectForKey:@"listinofs"]];
                if ([self.tableData count] != 0) {
                    [self.dbTableView reloadData];
                }
                break;
            case 10:
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"great!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alertView show];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

but the line under `case 10:` will report error `expected expression`, i don't understand, can you help me?

```
   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"great!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alertView show];
```

those codes report error.

Comment: Place the two statements for the alert view inside {} and all should be fine. Or change it to [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"great!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];

Answer (score -3):

Put NSLog over UIALertview and you will see that error will gone....Yes we can not directly initialise UIAlertview in switch case....it should be in {}.

```
switch (val) {
        case 10:
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"great!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }

            break;


    }
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment.